# find number distinct elements in a matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

say that I have a matrix A and an integer `E = 16`

```
A = [4  3   0.987477222842622;
8   4   0.987477222842622;
3   8   0.994241214094179;
12  5   0.951729278021845;
13  4   0.972221868548579;
14  13  0.996357467281480;
16  12  0.994198825847544]
```

It means that

```
element 4 is equal to element 3 with a similarity of 0.98, 
element 8 is equal to element 4 with a similarity of 0.98,
element 3 is equal to element 8 with a similarity of 0.99 etc..
```

please note that if element 13 is equal to element 4 (5th row) it doesn't mean that it is also equal to element 3 (since 4 is equal to 3 ,see first row). The similarity between 13 and 3 apparently is less than the threshold (0.95) to be considered equal.

In total there are `E=16` elements.

I would like to find the number of distinct elements...
In this case I have `16-5=11` different elements because the first 3 couples in the matrix `(4-3,8-4,3-8)` should be considered as a unique element...

That because

```
4-3 -> 1 element
8-4 -> 1 element
3-8 -> 1 element, but since 8 is equal to 4 that is equal to 3 they should considered as a unique element..
```

Do you have a solution for this problem?
it's driving me crazy :)

Comment: What makes the first three couples special? There are elements with higher and lower similarity which don't belong to this group.

Comment: I tried to complete the question...please have a look..

Comment: Consulting the 5th row, if element 13 is equal to element 4, would this equal to 3 as well? Consulting the 6th row, if element 14 is equal to 13, would this equal to 4, and then equal 3 as well?  Consulting the 7th row, would element 16 equal 12, which also equals 5?  If this is the case, you only have two distinct elements - the first row and the fourth row.  Please edit your question to make this clear.

Comment: Consulting the 5th row: no, element 13 is not equal to element 3 as well. The same for the other cases that you spoiled. That is because The matrix A is a selection of elements that have a similarity > thant 0.95. element 13 is similar with 3 with a similarity < than 0.95 so in short I consider them as different...

Comment: This extra constraint on similarity is nowhere in your post.  Please update your post to reflect this information.  By looking at your post, the similarity is there but it is not being used anywhere when determining which are similar elements.  Also, there are **no** rows where the similarity is `< 0.95`.  All of the rows have at least `0.95` or more in similarity.  Inconsistency is the root of all frustration :)

Comment: I updated the post even if the info about the similarity is not relevant at all..if it is not expilicity stated that 13 is equal to element 3 please consider them as not equal

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632499/find-group-of-elements-in-matrix-matlab for a better explanation