# find group of elements in matrix matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array of elements `E = [1 2 3 4 5 10]` and matrix A of couples of elements

```
A=[ 1 2;
    2 3;
    3 1;
    4 1;
    4 3;
    5 1]
```

You can read this matrix as

```
1 is similar (with a certain probability) to 2
2 is similar (with a certain probability) to 3
3 is similar (with a certain probability) to 1 etc...
```

I would like to know how many different groups of element are in the array E given the matrix A
In this case I have

```
1 group = 1 2 3
2 group = 1 3 4
3 group = 1 5
4 group = 10
```

so there are `4` different groups of elements in E

NOTE:

```
if 1 is similar to 2 (first row)
and if 5 is similar to 1 (sixth row)
5 is not similar to 2!!! (if it is not written anywhere)
```

so 1 2 5 don't belong to the same group

On the other hand

```
1 is similar to 2 (first row),
2 is similar to 3 (second row)
and  3 is similar to 1 (third row)
```

so 1 2 3 belong to the same group

Comment: So you're looking for all [`cliques`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)), right?

Comment: I didn't know about the cliques, but it seems like :D

Comment: What you want is all maximal cliques of the graph represented by `A`. Here are [some algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem). Note that the problem may take exponential time

Comment: can I use somehow the dendrogram function?